# Activity recreates Fragments on Orientation Change because reference is lost, how to avoid that?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-orientation

I'm trying to learn Android `Fragment`s and I have a very specific problem concerning `Fragment` management, because screen orientation screws up my implementation.

**EDIT: Already solved my problem, see the "Update" below.**

**Short version:**

Using static Fragments, if I change screen orientation, the reference to `R.id.fragment` is lost and the `Activity` re-creates the `Fragment` causing problems because another `Fragment` is still present on the Layout (because they're defined on the XML maybe).

**Context:**

I have a Master/Detail workflow using the default Eclipse template and I have a different type of `Fragment` for every tab on the ItemList. Ideally, what I want to do is switch between fragments, but I want to retain their current state without using the BackStack, since I want to navigate with the ItemList, and using the Back button to close the App.

I couldn't find any solutions for this specific problem and I tried with a lot of different approaches. Right now I'm using static fragments defined in the main Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment android:name="com.example.pintproject.DevicesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/devices"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

<fragment android:name="com.example.pintproject.ItemDetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

    </FrameLayout>
```

In the ItemListActivity `onCreate()`, I look for the `Fragment`s in the layout, and add them if they aren't created yet, and I hold a reference to the current active Detail `Fragment` so I can hide it / show the fragment I switch to.
I'm using hide/show instead of replace because replace destroys the Fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }




        df = (DevicesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.devices);

        if (df==null){
            df = new DevicesFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container,df).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(df).commit();
        }

        idf = (ItemDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail);

        if (idf==null){
            idf = new ItemDetailFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container,idf).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(idf).commit();

        }
        mContent = df;


@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.


        switch (Integer.valueOf(id)){

        case 1:{

            if (idf!=null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mContent).commit();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(idf).commit();
                mContent = idf;
            }

        }break;
        case 2:{

            if (df!=null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mContent).commit();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(df).commit();
                mContent = df;
            }

        }break;



        }


    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

With this approach, the `Fragment`s hide/show without any problems and hold the status, but if I make an Orientation Change, they are destroyed and recreated again. 
I know they are destroyed because I'm not using `setRetainInstance()`, but the problem is when I change orientation, the `Activity` loses the reference to the `Fragment`, and

```
df = (DevicesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.devices);
```

is null, so the program creates another Fragment. If I change the orientation again, not only the program re-creates two new Fragments, but two more `Fragment`s are somehow added to the layout and they aren't even hidden, they are shown one above another.

If I use `setRetainInstance()`, the `Fragment` holds the state when Orientation is changed, but still, the activity reference to the `Fragment` is null, and creates a new `Fragment` above the existing one, having two of each `Fragment`.

Example:

- I create `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B in Landscape orientation. Both work fine and I can switch between them.
- I change orientation to Portrait, `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B are destroyed and a new `Fragment` A' and `Fragment` B' are created, still, they work fine.
- I change orientation again to Landscape, `Fragment` A' and `Fragment` B' are destroyed, a new `Fragment` A'' and `Fragment` B'' are created, but the screen shows another `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B, both at the same time (one above another, let's call them residual), and these new A'' and B'' work fine but are shown above residual A and B.
- From this point on, every time I change orientation, 2 new `Fragment`s are added to the previous ones, but they don't even hold the previous state.

I hope the example is clear enough. I think the problem is the `Activity` not holding view references when the orientation is changed, creates them again and I don't really know how to work around that.

**UPDATE**:

I solved my problem by using `findFragmentByTag` instead of `findFragmentById`. Since I can now retrieve `Fragment` s already created, I have to add them to the container adding a specific tag to search for.

So my test code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
    df = (DevicesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("df");
    idf = (ItemDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("idf");



    if (savedInstanceState==null){

        if (df==null){
            df = new DevicesFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container,df, "df").commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(df).commit();
        }

        if (idf==null){
            idf = new ItemDetailFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container,idf,"idf").commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(idf).commit();

        }

    } else {


        Log.i("OUT","INSTANCE NOT NULL");
    }
    mContent = df;

}
```

This is fully functional, also have to `setRetainInstance(true)` for every `Fragment` and they hold their current state no matter how many times we change the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You must never hold a reference to the fragment. Instead. Whenever you need something from it, retrieve the reference for a short moment.

```
public ItemListFragment getItemListFragment() {
    return ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.item_list));
}
```

Then, whenever you need to **get** data from it, use

```
final ItemListFragment listFragment = getItemListFragment();
if (listFragment != null) {
    // do something
}
```

And avoid calling setters. You can define the setters, but it's a better practice to either pass an arguments when creating a Fragment or retrieve the data by getActivity() from the Fragment itself, as described below.

This is done because the Fragment lifecycle not always matches the Activity one.

If you ever have to call setter from Activity, don't forget to save the value in Fragment's onSaveInstanceState(), if needed.

So instead of calling

```
setActivateOnItemClick(true);
```

From Activity, do it from the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final YourActivity activity = (Activtity) getYourActivity();
    setActivateOnItemClick(activity.isMultiPane());
}
```

This way when the Fragment is re-created after Activity onCreate() (only in which you handle the value setting), it will has always access to the value

And define isMultiPane method from Activity, of course

```
public boolean isMultiPane() {
    return mTwoPane;
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, I only need the reference to hide/show the Fragment from the ItemList while keeping the data intact, I don't need to get any data (at least on this test). I solved it by using tags but I wonder if there's a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no answer yet, here is my opinion :

When your orientation changes, your fragment is being recreated and you loose your data, right ? I think this is exactly whete the "savedInstanceState" is made for :

> **Caution**: Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load alternative resources (such as the layout).

[Here is a link that can explain you how to handle that recreation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Hope this is useful to you ! =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  But that's not the solution I'm afraid (already tried that) the problem persists because R.id references are lost, and I don't know how to "retrieve" the already created Fragments from the previous orientation to handle them with the ItemList (to hide/show/control them).

Comment: Did you use the  findViewById(R.id.XXXX) before the 
if (savedInstanceState != null) { ?

Comment: Yes, if I use df = (DevicesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.devices); right before if (savedInstanceState!=null){ , df is null, so I can't retrieve it to control it , but savedInstaceState is NOT null, so the program won't create a new Fragment. But somehow if I setRetainInstance(true) on the Fragment the Fragment is still shown on the screen, but I can't control it with the ItemList... there must be something I'm missing somewhere.